# apache Camel: creating in memory file out of string rep of xml for http POST

Tags: java, groovy, apache-camel

I'm moving an existing Java listener to apache camel. The script puts together an xml String, then sands it as a file to a server with a POST. This happens about 5-10 times a minute. The created file is not stored anywhere, it is simply gets attached to the body and this is very unique and this is the part I don't know how to convert to camel - this is question #1. I have looked even at the API for a possibility to extract that file so I could append it to the body in camel. I know I could simply move the script over as Java/groovy, but I'd prefer to do this in camel... So far I've only seen File usage as a reference to a specific disk location, and writing thousands of files a day to disk just doesn't sound good, and these are very small files, between 10-30 lines of xml. Here is my question #2 - is there any way, in Java, or camel, that i could create a file without a path to the file?
Below is the Java that I would like to replace, and a little lower is what I have in camel so far:

```
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.ContentBody;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.StringBody;
import org.apache.http.entity.ContentType;

String xml = "my xml string";
String filename = "something"+id+".xml";

ContentBody strBody = new StringBody(xml, org.apache.http.entity.ContentType.APPLICATION_ATOM_XML){
    public String getFilename(){
            return filename;
    }
};                        
FormBodyPart fbp = FormBodyPartBuilder.create("upload_file[]", strBody).build();
HttpEntity reqEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
    .setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE)
    .addPart(fbp) 
.build();
httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
```

My CAMEL snipplet:

```
    <route>
        <setBody>            
            <groovy>
                <![CDATA[
                    String xml = null;
                    .......
                    xml;
                ]]>                        
            </groovy>
        </setBody>

        <filter>
            <simple>${body} != null</simple>
            <log message=">>> XML: ${headers.cmsContentType}, ${headers.contentID}\n body${}" logName="fwIngest"/>
            <inOnly uri="activemq:fwPost"/>                
        </filter>
    </route>

    <route id="fwPost">
        <from uri="activemq:fwPost?concurrentConsumers=4" />
        <onException>
            ...
        </onException>            
        <setHeader headerName="X-Token">
            <simple>{{token}}</simple>
        </setHeader>            
        <setHeader headerName="CamelHttpMethod">
            <constant>POST</constant>
        </setHeader>
        <setHeader headerName="Content-Type">
            <constant>multipart/form-data</constant>
        </setHeader>

        <to uri="https://api.tv/services/...proxyPort=8080"/>                                               
        <log message="POST ResponseCode: ${headers.CamelHttpResponseCode}, ResponseText: ${headers.CamelHttpResponseText}" logName="fwPost"/>            
    </route>
```

Comment: You can start by checking [Apache Http client Camel component](http://camel.apache.org/http4.html)

Comment: @AntonKrosnev: I saw the component. While it has some handy features, i did not see anything multi-part related.